# If 1 can be a random number in Diffie-Hellman Algorithm

Tags: diffie-hellman, keys, key-exchange

I've done some calculations and Diffie-Hellman Algorithm worked for all chosen random numbers except $1$. In the description of the algorithm, I can't find information that the random number has to be higher than $1 (r>1)$.

- Could you explain to me if I made a mistake or where I can find information that $r$ cannot be $1$?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work for 1? Can you please describe the problem there / give an example? (Preferably using an [edit]?)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) says from $1$ to $p-1$. Could you provide your source?

Comment: My best guess is that you're using an existing DH library which has been programmed to reject the $r=1$ case...

Comment: Of course such "errors" would go unnoticed for a sufficiently large maximum for $r$, which would be the case for *any* known set of secure parameters. The chance of generating 0 or 1 would be insignificant, and even if it was generated it is likely that it is simply rejected and that a new random is generated. Basically it is just slightly annoying when you're performing boundary tests. By the way, you were asked for a source, and I might close the question without one, as we cannot seem to answer otherwise.